# Is it possible to solve Error in Ops.data.frame: ‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames in r?

Tags: r

I'm having trouble sub-setting my data while working.
My data is:

```
structure(list(Tissues = c("Hairy_root", "Hairy_root", "Adventitious_root", 
"Adventitious_root", "Embryonic_root", "Embryonic_root", "Leaf", 
"Leaf"), Replicate = c("R1", "R2", "R1", "R2", "R1", "R2", "R1", 
"R2"), ACT = c(23.13958, 24.04483881, 23.04186967, 23.30146732, 
24.20995687, 24.29608776, 24.40250502, 23.39981921), DnaJ = c(22.03439246, 
26.60619229, 21.88943566, 27.85283015, 22.42216211, 23.44923267, 
23.16443426, 23.1289117), `EF-1` = c(22.68375722, 23.44663203, 
22.30853321, 24.71161093, 22.78175571, 23.12476878, 23.60114283, 
23.08036574), TUB = c(21.68375722, 23.44663203, 21.30853321, 
23.71161093, 21.78175571, 22.12476878, 23.60114283, 22.08036574
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

my code and function is:

```
    Tot_ACT <- tibble()
comparisons <- c()
for (r in 1:8){
    comparisons <- c(comparisons, paste(Cq_rf[,1], "and", Cq_rf[r,1]))
    Tot_ACT <- add_column(as.data.frame(comparisons))}
zed <- c(4,5,6)
for (z in zed){
    diff_list <- c()
    differences <- c()
    for (r in 1:8){
        differences <- Cq_rf[,3] - Cq_rf[r,z]
        diff_list <- c(diff_list , differences)}
    Tot_ACT <- Tot_ACT %>% add_column(as.data.frame(diff_list))}
c_names <- c("Comparisons", "ACT vs DnaJ", "ACT vs EF-1","ACT vs TUB")
colnames(Tot_ACT) <- c_names
```

But after running the above code, I face the following problem:

Error in Ops.data.frame(Cq_rf[, 3], Cq_rf[r, z]) :
‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames

Comment: You shouldn't subtract data.frames from each other. If you want to do that, it is a sign that you should use a matrix as data structure. Anyway, when looking at `Cq_rf[,3] - Cq_rf[r,z]`, with `r` incrementing from 1 to 8, it is clear that you are trying to subtract matrix-like objects from each other that are not the same size. Mathematically, subtraction is only defined for matrices of the same size. Thus, what you are trying to do is not possible. Maybe you intend something else but we don't know what you intend.